# Avg Page Load time is 0.00 for pageviews > 100 in a week and its higher for p.v. <100 in a week

Tags: google-analytics, page-speed, page-views

Some of the pages in my client's website are with pageviews > 100 in a week, although the Avg Page Load Time is 0.00 sec

and if PageViews < 100 in a week, although the Avg Page Time is displayed.

I understand that timing metrics are based on 1% of data collected by default; I also read Google's documentation https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?topic=1120718&hl=en

But this doesn't explain why I am getting such data. Is this a sampling issue or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, by default, a fixed 1% sampling of your site visitors make up the data pool from which the Site Speed metrics are derived.

So, the problem is that **you don’t get enough traffic on this site for the sample size to be significant**, therefore, zeros came up in your reports.

> If you have a relatively small number of daily visitors to your site, such as 100,000 or fewer, you might want to adjust the sampling to a larger rate

In order to do that, set the [SiteSpeedSampleRate](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate) higher than one.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 10});
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this. Although, what surprises me is a page with 60 pageviews has the Avg loading time 3.22seconds, however a page with 136 pageviews has the Avg loading time 0.00 seconds. So is this the issue with sampling or something else?

Comment: The sample rate is based on 1% of users (not URLs). You don't know which users have visited what URLs in your site, that's why some pages have speed metrics and others don't despite the pageviews. If you increase the sample rate, you will have more chances that the new sample gets users who generated pageviews in all URLs.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.